# Adding feature to highlight layer forces redraw of original layer

Tags: openlayers

I have two VectorLayers setup, one for my actual features and another one for highlights (I'm rendering ~10000 features so I have a separate layer for highlight as [recommended by ahocevar](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/8514#issuecomment-413569338)).

However, whenever I add/remove features to the highlight layer, it seems that the original layer is forced to be redrawn again, even though there was no interaction with that particular layer (besides hit detection).

Am I doing something wrong or does OL always rerenders all the layers when one of them changes?

Comment: OpenLayers currently uses a single canvas for the map and all layers are rendered to that.  In the next release https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/master/changelog/upgrade-notes.md each layer will have its own canvas.  You might want to test your code with the version 6 beta (for a quick test of the full build use https://openlayers.org/en/master/build/ol.js and https://openlayers.org/en/master/css/ol.css ) to see if there is any performance improvement.

Comment: Also, if you are having performance issue with slow rendering of vectors make sure your style function is efficient and is using pre-generated styles wherever possible instead of creating new ones for each feature.

Comment: I've now checked the OpenLayers example https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/examples/vector-layer.html with version 4 and version 6 beta and pre/post compose/render events fire on both layers.  So what you are seeing seems unavoidable at present.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. All the styles are created beforehand and returned on the style function. I wonder if there is anyway to access the vectorContext outside of the render events? I could simply draw the highlighted feature directly to the canvas.

Comment: With a single map canvas `vectorContext = ol.render.toContext(map.getViewport().getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0].getContext('2d'));`  I'm not sure how to identify individual layer canvases in future versions.

Comment: I tried that, the problem is then how to "delete" the feature, since it's drawn on top of the rest ;) I could use a separate canvas for that, but then I'd have to keep the map and the overlay canvas in sync

Comment: You would have to force a re-render to clear it (so no gain there), but you would have avoided unnecessary rendering setting it, it's a 50% improvement.